# Merge historical periods of an dimension entity into one

Tags: sql, t-sql, business-intelligence, dimension

I have a Slowly Changing Dimension type 2 with rows that are identical (besides the Start and End date). How do I write a pretty SQL query to merge rows that identical and have connected time periods?

**Current data**

```
+-------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+
| DimensionID | DimensionAttribute  | RowStartDate | RowEndDate |
+-------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+
|           1 | SomeValue           | 2019-01-01   | 2019-01-31 |
|           1 | SomeValue           | 2019-02-01   | 2019-02-28 |
|           1 | AnotherValue        | 2019-03-01   | 2019-03-31 |
|           1 | SomeValue           | 2019-04-01   | 2019-04-30 |
|           1 | SomeValue           | 2019-05-01   | 2019-05-31 |
|           2 | SomethingElse       | 2019-01-01   | 2019-01-31 |
|           2 | SomethingElse       | 2019-02-01   | 2019-02-28 |
|           2 | SomethingElse       | 2019-03-01   | 2019-03-31 |
|           2 | CompletelyDifferent | 2019-04-01   | 2019-04-30 |
|           2 | SomethingElse       | 2019-05-01   | 2019-05-31 |
+-------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+
```

**Result**

```
+-------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+
| DimensionID | DimensionAttribute  | RowStartDate | RowEndDate |
+-------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+
|           1 | SomeValue           | 2019-01-01   | 2019-02-28 |
|           1 | AnotherValue        | 2019-03-01   | 2019-03-31 |
|           1 | SomeValue           | 2019-04-01   | 2019-05-31 |
|           2 | SomethingElse       | 2019-01-01   | 2019-03-31 |
|           2 | CompletelyDifferent | 2019-04-01   | 2019-04-30 |
|           2 | SomethingElse       | 2019-05-01   | 2019-05-31 |
+-------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: Search Gaps and Islands, there are plenty of examples out there. Have a go and if you get stuck show your attempts. SO isn't a free coding service. We're happy to help you when you've tried, and failed, to solve the problem yourself but you first need to make that effort. Thanks.

Comment: How would you handle the data if there were a gap between two otherwise identical rows?

Comment: At @Longluck , Stack Overflow is for asking coding/programming questions. The reason people ask a question here is *because* they have tried and failed to solve the problem themselves. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions that ask for "ideas" are off-topic for Stack Overflow, as it isn't a discussion website. The reason, therefore, that myself and others will see this as "asking for code", is that that is exactly what SO is for, asking for code solutions to a problem. And that is *exactly* the answer you got.

Comment: @Larnu Where does it say the question should have code in it? Could I have added my failed attempt to solve the issue, sure? But in this situation I don't think it would have added any value to the understanding of the problem. You attack me straight of the gate, thinking I have preconceived ideas that people will do my work for me. Thinking I haven't tried anything beforehand and that I didn't make an effort. I actually took my real problem and tried to strip it from everything that has to do with my real work in order to make the question as plain and simple as possible.

Comment: Part of asking a question here is showing your attempts. I haven't attacked you at all. There are expectations and ways to ask on stack Overflow, and one of those is showing your efforts. That could be code, that might be research and descriptions of what you don't understand. Questions that don't show that effort, however, will often result in few answers, or downvotes, as the users here are using their free time to help you. As a result we do expect that you try and show your efforts. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this version of the problem, I would use `lag()` to determine where the groups start, then a cumulative sum and aggregation:

```
select dimensionid, DimensionAttribute,
       min(row_start_date), max(row_end_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_red = dateadd(day, -1, row_start_date)
                      then 0 else 1
                 end) over (partition by dimensionid, DimensionAttribute order by row_start_date) as grp
      from (select t.*, 
                   lag(row_end_date) over (partition by dimensionid, DimensionAttribute order by row_start_date) as prev_red
            from t 
           ) t
     ) t
group by dimensionid, DimensionAttribute, grp;
```

In particular, this will recognize gaps in the rows.  It will only combine rows when they exactly fit together -- the previous end date is one day before the start date.  This can be tweaked, of course, to allow a gap of 1 or 2 days or to allow overlaps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hadn't thought of using sum and window function to create separate groups into my dataset. I works like a charm :)